# Does there exists in physics an operator satisfies: $A^{-1}(t)=A(-t+ i \beta)$ , $\beta$ is a real number non-null?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, unitarity

Let $  t$  be a real number such that present the time. Really am interesting to know if there exists an operator satisfies the below property:

$$A^{-1}(t)=A(-t+ i \beta)$$ $\beta$ is a real number non-null and $  A^{-1} $  is the compositional  inverse of $ A$  , For instance I have got only the Unitary Operator as exponential form which it's used widely in quantum mechanics as shown [here](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/voices.uchicago.edu/dist/0/1830/files/2019/07/Exponential-Operators.pdf) but it satisfies only :$U^{-1}(t)=U(-t)$

**Note 01:** In Have edited my question without changing the meaning of it and for the given answer , I didn't meant by U in my titled equality the unitary operator but it is an operator which i search on it

**Note 02:** The motivation of this question is to know more about chaotic operators

Comment: Can you provide a bit more physical context? What other properties do you want $U(t)$ to satisfy?

Comment: Ok , for Other property i want U = U* to get a hermitian operator , I will add that in my question i missed that

Comment: @BySymmetry, Another reformulation of the titled question is : Does the Hermitian operator satisfy the titled equality ?

Comment: can some connection be made to KMS boundary condition?

Comment: Could you elaborate in what context does this requirement appears? how did you come up with this rule?

Comment: The motivation of this question is to know more about chaotic operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a bit confused by your desideratum, but if you had a unitary  operator $W(t)=\exp (itH)$, so 
$$
W(t) W(-t)=1\!\! 1,
$$
You could define 
$$
U(t)\equiv W(t) ~~e^{-\beta H/2},
$$
so that 
$$
U(t) U(-t+i\beta) = W(t) ~~e^{-\beta H/2}  W(-t+i\beta) ~~e^{-\beta H/2}=
e^{ i H (t- i \beta/2 -t +i\beta -i\beta/2  )}=1\!\! 1 ,
$$
no?

Comment: But in my question U^(-1) is compositional inverse of U not a reciprocal (multiplicative)  inverse .

Comment: @zeraouliarafik That doesnt make any sense. If $U\colon \mathbb R\to\mathcal H$, then the compositional inverse is $U^{-1}\colon\mathcal H\to\mathbb R$, and so you cannot possibly have $U^{-1}(t)=U(-t+i\beta)$.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik your baseline QM example is definitely multiplicative, no?

Comment: No, i asked for which operator such that  the titled equality Holds , Probably it will hold for some partition of Rational numbers  like (-1,1)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform , Sorry in my titled question i didn't meant the operator is unitary i have edited that

Comment: @zeraouliarafik how is that relevant? unitary or not, the equation only makes sense if the inverse is in the multiplicative sense. (Also, in QM operators are always linear, so composition is the same as multiplication...)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, Could u show me how compositional inverse is the same with multiplicative inverse in QM may in the given answer ?